# How to bind Docker Container Running Apache to domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, devops, amazon-route53

I deployed application based on this [stack](https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/drupal/local/) on AWS where under Rout 53 DNS is set. I want to point my domain (exampl.com) to web server (any apache/nginx) running in docker container. I want to know how can i bind domain to that web server?

I am not sure it's good or bad way to deploy an application on production but it will help me to understand.

Comment: how did you deploy this stack on AWS. in other words, which aws service are you using to run this stack? for e.g elasticbeanstalk, ec2, ecs etc

Comment: @ArunK I used ec2. Ubuntu, installed docker and run my docker-compose. On my local machine I added project url with 127.0.0.1 example.com in hosts file. here I am not able to understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

as @mipnw suggested, you can easily run your Docker containers in Amazon ECS.

Since you are not using ECS, here is how you can point the domain to the ec2 instance.

1. Assign an elastic IP address to the ec2 instance

   Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-associate-static-public-ip/
2. Create an `A` record in AWS Route53 to point to the elastic IP address.

   Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-create-alias-records/
3. if your docker is exposing for e.g port `80` to the host machine.

   Now you can access your application via http://example.com (since http default port is 80), for that you should enable port 80 in your instance's security group

   Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/
4. If your docker is exposing port for e.g `8080` and you want to access the website via http://example.com, you will need to configure apache/nginx proxy to accept the traffic via port `80` or `443` and forward the request to the port exposed by docker (8080 in this example)

   Reference: https://dev.to/kevbradwick/how-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-to-your-host-machine-using-docker-mii

The most difficult part of your setup is setting up SSL, you would need to configure the SSL certificate inside the nginx proxy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Running docker in ECS is anything but easy. You have to correctly configure about a dozen services for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to host your docker container somewhere. Since you're already using AWS I'd suggest running your container inside [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

Then you'll have expose a port on the container, and configure Route53 to point to  your container etc... It looks like [ECS Service Discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/) makes it easier to register your service running inside ECS with Route53.

Comment: @mipnq, I am using ec2. docker containers are running, thing that I am not able to understand is how to point outer world traffic to application inside docker container to see html/json response. I can host application running with apache without docker where i need to create a virtual host (directory <-> domain/url), but in this docker case I am not sure what to do to fetch application by url from outer world over internet.